# MVC 4 button not working in partial view - confusion over use of Html.beginForm and where am posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, view, partial-views

I have a button in my partial view that is not working and I am not sure why. I have general questions for the layout of my view and partial view but mainly I want my button to work.

This is my main cshtml markup:

```
@model IMecheAdmin.Models.InterviewManagement
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InterviewManagementPage";
}

    <div style="padding: 10px">
        <h4>
            Interview Management Page</h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label("Select a membership type:")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMembershipType,
new SelectList(Model.InterviewTypes, "InterviewTypeID", "InterviewTypeName"), new { id = "lstMembershipType", onchange = "getGridValues();" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getGridValues() {
            var interviewTypeID = $('#lstMembershipType').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getGridData", "InterviewManagement")',
                data: { interviewTypeID: interviewTypeID },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#gridData').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div id="gridData" style="padding: 10px">
        @{

    Html.RenderAction("getGridData");
        }
    </div>
```

My RenderAction is used to render my partial view. It has it's own partial actionresult method called getGridData.

```
Html.RenderAction("getGridData");
```

At the moment my begin form block is in my partial view Partial_InterviewManageGrid.cshtml. Shown below:

```
@model IMecheAdmin.Models.InterviewManagement

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmittedInterviews", "InterviewManagement", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model.InterviewDates.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.InterviewSchedules.Count; i++)
        {
        @Html.Label("Date of interview:")
        @Html.Label(Model.InterviewDates[i].DateOfInterview.ToString())
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Site
                </td>
                <td>
                    Location
                </td>
                <td>
                    Chair
                </td>
                <td>
                    Cofacilitator
                </td>
                <td>
                    Facilitator
                </td>
                <td>
                    Observer
                </td>
                <td>
                    Preference
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var person in Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[i].Chair, Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers.Select(p => p.InterviewerName).ToList(), new { @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                        @Html.Raw(person.InterviewerName)  
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var person in Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[i].Cofacilitator, Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers.Select(p => p.InterviewerName).ToList(), new { @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                        @Html.Raw(person.InterviewerName)  
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var person in Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[i].Facilitator, Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers.Select(p => p.InterviewerName).ToList(), new { @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                        @Html.Raw(person.InterviewerName)  
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var person in Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[i].Observer, Model.InterviewDates[i].Interviewers.Select(p => p.InterviewerName).ToList(), new { @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                        @Html.Raw(person.InterviewerName)  
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        }

        if (Model.InterviewDates.Count > 0)
        {
        <input type="button" value="Confirm interview"/>

        }

        <hr />
    }
}
```

I have an ActionResult method that is very basic right now, the breakpoint doesn't get hit for this and my browser doesn't show any GETs or POSTs.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmittedInterviews(InterviewManagement InterviewManagement)
        {
            return View(InterviewManagement);
        }
```

- Should my html.beginform be in the view or partial view?
- How do I make it go to this actionResult? There is no view called SubmittedInterviews right now. Just the method in my controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a partial view is loaded after the main page, the button click event isn't tied to the button. To get it to work you need to attach your click event to the document.
Give your button a class to select on:

```
<input type="button" value="Confirm interview" class="btnConfirm"/>
```

then on your main view

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnConfirm', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            //do something
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: When I click the button I want to submit my model. I want to avoid posting my model as a JSON string using jQuery. I don't know my click event code would be inside the jQuery?

Comment: what are you wanting to do?  My code would allow you to do an ajax call and save just the partial view data but that would be using JSON.  Is there a reason you don't want to use JSON?

Comment: In the past I've had my model as a parameter and it's more straightforward because I already have the object. I am having problem passing my model to the javascript. Do you have any good code for this?

Comment: if you put a form tag around your partial view you can do a form.serialize to pass the fields from the partial.  see my changed code above

Comment: I am no longer in the office but I will definitely give this ago tomorow and reply back.

Comment: Set your button type to submit.

Comment: @KevDevMan Hey I changed my input type to submit and then I got rid of the jQuery and changed action method parameter to my object. I think I made it a little bit overcomplicated. Thanks for your help!